# android button green

Tags: android, button, android-button

i would like to have tha default button but not in gray.

I need to change the color green/blue/red.

I would like to do this thanks to xml but also from the code.

I need to have a green button which change the color of all the other button.

It's why i need to change from xml and from the code.

Comment: you only have to set color of button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define you colors in the color resource so it is easier to apply your desired colors via code or xml.